# Best way to store data securely?

Tags: java, database, datastore

I am looking for way to store some data. I want to users of my program to be able to choose a way to store data. They can choose database (PostgreSQL, MySQL) and I want to give opportunity to choose easier way for newbie users so they don't have to install database system. When they start my program for the first time they're passing user data (login/password) and the some data made by my program are stored on HDD of user. Is it any library (for Java) or something like db but configured automatically when that let me do this? I mean, I want to create some tables like in db and have an easy access to them. But they should be secured (access only with login/password passed at the first time). I hope you will understand me. It was difficult to explain what I want :)

Comment: I would re-word the title, @latata. "Best" is rather subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an embedded DB, like [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/). See also the [Working with encryption](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/devguide/cdevcsecure97760.html) article.

Answer (score 3):

If i'm understood right you need embedded SQL DB engine that can store data encripted? Take look at [h2 databse](http://www.h2database.com/)
it's lightweight and has this

```
Security Features

Includes a solution for the SQL injection problem
User password authentication uses SHA-256 and salt
For server mode connections, user passwords are never transmitted in plain text over the network (even when using insecure connections; this only applies to the TCP server and not to the H2 Console however; it also doesn't apply if you set the password in the database URL)
All database files (including script files that can be used to backup data) can be encrypted using AES-128 and XTEA encryption algorithms
The remote JDBC driver supports TCP/IP connections over SSL/TLS
The built-in web server supports connections over SSL/TLS
Passwords can be sent to the database using char arrays instead of Strings
```